# search and replace using dictionary on files

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am trying to write a program to read the input from a file a.txt

```
Hi this is nick, I am male and I am 30 years old.
```

and replace the name, age and gender of people and write it to a new file b.txt.
Below is my try.

```
orig_file=open("a.txt","r") # file handle 
new_file=open("b.txt","w")    # new file handle
temp_buffer=orig_file.read()
lookup_dict={"nick":"andrea", "male":"female", "30":"20"}

for line in temp_buffer:
    for word in lookup_dict:
        line= line.replace(word, lookup_dict[word])
        new_file.write(line)
```

My expected result for b.txt is

```
Hi this is andrea, I am female and I am 20 years old.
```

observed output (b.txt)

```
HHHiii   ttthhhiiisss   iiisss   nnniiiccckkk,,,   III   aaammm   mmmaaallleee   aaannnddd   III   aaammm   333000   yyyeeeaaarrrsss   ooolllddd...
```

Could someone explain what I am doing wrong and correct me.

Comment: What error or wrong output do you get?

Comment: hi @match, i have updated the question with the observed output.

Comment: `temp_buffer=orig_file.read()` will read all the chars into temp_buffer but not as lines. Maybe you wanted to do `temp_buffer=orig_file.readlines()` then itertate over each line, currently you iterate over each char 3 times and print it 3 times. you also want to unindent the write line so that your not writing the line for each word you replace. just write the line at the end of all the word replacements

Comment: Thanks @ChrisDoyle, now it all makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `readlines` instead of `read` and call `close()` on the files manually, since you are not using **[`with`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)**:

```
orig_file = open("a.txt", "r")  # file handle
new_file = open("b.txt", "w")  # new file handle
temp_buffer = orig_file.readlines()
orig_file.close()
lookup_dict = {"nick": "andrea", "male": "female", "30": "20"}
for line in temp_buffer:
    for word in lookup_dict:
        line = line.replace(word, lookup_dict[word])
    new_file.write(line)
new_file.close()
```

**b.txt:**

```
Hi this is andrea, I am female and I am 20 years old.
```